# Get `value_type` of inner nested vector

Tags: c++

How do I get the `value_type` of the inner-most of an n-dimensional vector?

In particular, I would like to each time obtain `type_name` to be `double` for the example as follows:

```cpp
#include <vector>

template <class T>
void foo(const T& data)
{
    // ??
    using type_name = typename T::value_type;

    type_name a;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> a;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> b;

    foo(a);
    foo(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @NathanOliver - yes, this is a better duplicate. I thought there is an answer in my duplicate which handled the case OP asked about, but it wasn't there, while yours does have it.

Comment: @NathanOliver - Thanks, somehow I missed that answer in my search!